# extremely short power interruption causes PC reset

Tags: power-supply

I am trying to evaluate the following sentence from a customer:

"a 30 milliseconds power interruption has caused a reset of a personal computer".

This specific PC has a 600W power supply.

Is it  possible that a 30 milliseconds power interruption can have caused this issue?

Comment: Why do you think the wattage of the power supply matters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few facts to start with:

- In a 50Hz grid, a complete cycle is 20ms
- In a 60Hz grid, a complete cycle is ca. 17ms.
- Consumer PC power suplies are typically designed to survive a single cycle power loss (i.e.: The combination of amount of energy stored in the PSU's LC elements and the fill- and empty-rate of these allow to recover the amount of energy used in a single cycle)
- Server power supplies are typically designed to survive 2-3 cycles, but only if all (in a redundant PSU setting) are present and operative. They should survive a single cycle even in emergency mode (no more redundancy)
- UPSes are designed to switch over within 8ms (60Hz) resp. 10ms (50Hz), which is half a cycle.

Now: A 30ms interruption is close to a 2-cycle energy loss on a 60Hz grid, this would imply, that if a standard consumer PC PSU were to supply a load of a bit over 50% and designed to the usual standard, it would indeed drop out of the voltage window and signal this via the PWRGOOD signal to the mainboard. If this were to immediately assert a power failure (and not delay for a few ms), the chipset would shut down hard.

On return of power (ca. 50ms later: 30ms brownout plus PSU restart) it would do a cold boot.

Comment: In other words the customer needs a UPS to prevent what they described from happening in the future